# Let $T_n,T$ be operators on a Banach space $X$ such that $x_n\to x\implies T_n(x_n)\to T(x)$. Does $T_n\to T$ in norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Fix some Banach space $X$, and let $T_n,T\in\mathscr{L}(X)$ be bounded linear operators on $X$, such that for any convergent sequence $x_n\to x$ in $X$, we have that $T_n(x_n)\to T(x)$. Then does $T_n\to T$ in norm?

Clearly, this property implies strong convergence, and is implied by convergence in norm. But is it equivalent to either of these properties?

Comment: A hint:  $\lVert T_n x_n - T x \rVert \le \lVert T_n \rVert \lVert x_n - x \rVert + \lVert T_n x - Tx\rVert$.  Do you know the [Banach-Steinhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle)?

Comment: Yes, but the version on Wikipedia only seems to show finiteness of the sup over $n\ge1$ and $\|x\|\le1$, not that the sup can be made arbitrarily small, and therein lies my problem.

Comment: From the answers by Hans Engler and Tsemo Aristide you see that the property is not equivalent to convergence in norm.  So, perhaps it is equivalent to some other convergence?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = \ell^2$ and consider $T_nx = (0,\dots,0,x_n, x_{n+1}, \dots)$ for $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots) \in \ell^2$, together with $T = 0$. Your assumptions are true, but $T_n$ does not converge to  $T$ in norm.

Comment: I see now. Is the property equivalent to strong convergence however?

Comment: That was my hint.

Comment: While I’m familiar with the statement of Banach-Steinhaus, I don’t quite see how to use it here.

Comment: If $\lVert x_n - x\rVert \to 0$ and $\lVert T_n \rVert$ are bounded, what then?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $C([0,1])$ the space of continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$ and $f_n$ defined by $f(x)=0, x\geq {1\over n}$ or $x\leq {1\over{n+1}}$. the restriction of $f$ to $[{1\over {n+1}}, {{2n+1}\over{2n(n+1)}}]$ is affine and $f({{2n+1}\over{2n(n+1)}})=1$, the restriction of $f$ to $[{{2n+1}\over{2n(n+1)}},{1\over n}]$ is affine. Then $lim_nf_n(x)=0$ and $\|f_n-0\|=sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f_n(x)-0|=1$.